# XSLT transformation to dynamically add empty elements based on the maximum count of element present

Tags: xml, xslt

Following XML is my Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main1</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content1</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer1</EE1>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main2</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content2</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer2.1</EE1>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer2.2</EE1>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer2.3</EE1>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main3</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content3</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer3</EE1>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
</Item>
```

count of node EE should be equal in all CC parent tag (this count is the maximum of EE within the CC)

In my example the maximum count of EE tag is 3. Is it possible to dynamically add EE elements by getting this count? 
If there is no value, then i will populate with non breking white space.
so after transformation my xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main1</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content1</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer1</EE1>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE2>       </EE2>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE3>       </EE3>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main2</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content2</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer2.1</EE1>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE2>Answer2.2</EE2>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE3>Answer2.3</EE3>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main3</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content3</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer3</EE1>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE2>       </EE2>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE3>        </EE3>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
</Item>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **1.** Your input is not valid XML (it has no single root element). -- **2.** Please state if you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I appologize for that @michael.hor257k. I have edited this. xslt version is 1.0

Comment: @Sowmiya, The currently accepted answer doesn't in fact produce the output that you specified as wanted. See my answer for a transformation, which produces exactly the wanted result and doesn't use recursion to create N missing elements (when N is hundreds or more a recursion may crash due to stack-overflow!).

Comment: It would have been more appropriate to comment on @michael.hor257k 's answer, otherwise he won't get notified of these concerns. However, I have to admit, you have a point.

Comment: @Flynn1179 What point would that be?

Comment: Your answer is producing the wrong result, I tried it myself. At the time of the comment, Dimitre's answer included a description of what was wrong with the output, but since the OP changed their accepted answer, he removed it.

Comment: @Flynn1179 My answer was written before OP changed the required output. I did not consider it necessary to modify my answer, because the required change is trivial and (so I thought) OP understood that. I have now added the required modification.

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice the change to the question; your original answer certainly does provide exactly what was originally asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is one correct solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vMax">
    <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/CC">
      <xsl:sort select="count(EE)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(EE)"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="vNodes" select="(//*)[not(position() > $vMax)]"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vEmpty" select="'&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CC">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
          "$vNodes[not(position() > $vMax - count(current()/EE))]" mode="picture">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="count(EE)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CC/EE/EE1">
    <xsl:element name="EE{count(../preceding-sibling::EE)+1}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="picture">
    <xsl:param name="pStart" select="0"/>
    <EE>
      <xsl:element 
        name="EE{$pStart + position()}"><xsl:value-of select="$vEmpty"/></xsl:element>
    </EE>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Item>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main1</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content1</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer1</EE1>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main2</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content2</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer2.1</EE1>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer2.2</EE1>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer2.3</EE1>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main3</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content3</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer3</EE1>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
</Item>
```

**the exactly-wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Item>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main1</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content1</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer1</EE1>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE2>       </EE2>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE3>       </EE3>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main2</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content2</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer2.1</EE1>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE2>Answer2.2</EE2>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE3>Answer2.3</EE3>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
   <Description>
      <BB>Main3</BB>
      <CC>
         <DD>Content3</DD>
         <EE>
            <EE1>Answer3</EE1>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE2>       </EE2>
         </EE>
         <EE>
            <EE3>       </EE3>
         </EE>
      </CC>
   </Description>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="max-ee">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Item/Description/CC">
        <xsl:sort select="count(EE)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(EE)"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CC">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="gen-ee">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="count(EE)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="gen-ee">
    <xsl:param name="i" />
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt; $max-ee">
        <EE/>
        <xsl:call-template name="gen-ee">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i +1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>        
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To produce the output in your **modified** question, change this line in the last template:

```
<EE/>
```

to:

```
<EE>
    <xsl:element name="EE{$i + 1}">&#160;</xsl:element>
</EE>
```

---

Note that the existing `EE1` elements will not be renumbered - although that too would be rather trivial to do by adding a template:

```
<xsl:template match="EE1">
    <xsl:element name="EE{count(../preceding-sibling::EE) + 1}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```